# Excluding strange pages with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I have a strange situation occurring on my site where google thinks certain php pages are children of other php pages.  For example, I am getting errors in Google Webmaster tools for pages showing up like: http://domain.com/page1.php/page5.php.  Both page1.php and page5.php exist on the site, but I can't figure out why google thinks one should be concatenated to the other.

Browsing to such a link will load page1.php, but not correctly.  My goal was to use .htaccess (or other suggestions) to simply redirect to the first page if additional pages follow.  Am I thinking about this correctly, and can anyone offer suggestions to help me resolve this?  Thanks!

Update: The only lines in my .htaccess file are redirecting from a previous folder structure to a single php file, but this has been in place for at least a year.  For example:

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/widgets/?$ http://firesage.com/widgets.php`

Update2: I just found this 'Soft 404' error in Webmaster tools: http://domain.com/page2.php/include/include/lookup.php?id=22.  First, I have the include folder excluded via robots.txt.  And the fact that the include folder is listed twice in the url is very suspect.

Comment: Google is just following links (and reading your sitemap file...), so instead of making wrong links / urls load correctly, you'd better make sure your links are exactly what they need to be.

Comment: That's the strange thing, these urls aren't found in Google search, rather in Google Webmaster tools.  They seem to be reducing my ranking, but my sitemap is clean and I can't find sites using this url to link to my site.  I have no idea where this is coming from.

Comment: That's what the Google's *crawler* finds when crawling your site...

Comment: You can take a look at Traffic > Internal links and see if they appear there.

Comment: Traffic > Internal links shows nothing out of the ordinary.  :(

Comment: Perhaps there are external sites linking to these pages, you can check that in the server logs and probably Google Analytics (assuming you use that...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you can use `.htaccess` to redirect Google, but I would rather suggest you find the reason why Google sees those "wrong" links (s. Jeroen's comment to your question). Here's the `.htaccess` to start up with, until you've found the reason.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymLinks

# every page on its own
RewriteRule ^page1.php/(.*)$ /page1.php [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^page2.php/(.*)$ /page2.php [R=301,L]
# or in general maybe the following to replace all of the above, if you think it'll fit
# RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)\.php/(.*)$ /$1.php [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

**Update**
If you also need to pass any possible `GET` parameters, just add the `QSA` flag so it becomes `[R=301,L,QSA]`.

Comment: The pages with this issue shouldn't be accessed with subdirectories, so I am looking for the easiest method to simply redirect to the primary page.   Using your example above, would the following work if any subdirectories are located: RewriteRule ^page1.php/$ /page1.php [R=301,L] ?  The only exclusion is when a get variable is appended to the url, such as ?id=234

Comment: So you'd like something like `domain.com/<something>/pageX.php` to be redirected to `domain.com/pageX.php`? If that's so, how about the `<something>` part? Is it supposed to be `dirName0-9` only or could it also be subdiretories like `dirname0/dirname1/.../dirName9`? Let's first clarify this and then about the exclusions :)

Comment: Fair enough. Page names aren't uniform, so it will have to be one line per page.  I would like domain.com/pageX.php/anything/here/should.be/ignored to simply be redirected to domain.com/pageX.php.  I'm not sure if the hosting provider (1and1) is assisting in the problem, but the page won't load properly with the extra directories appended to the original page.

Comment: I've updated my answer now to match your criteria from above. As you can see you can do it for every single page with its own `RewriteRule` or the last one which I commented out will redirect `domain.com/<something>.php/anything/here/should.be/ignored` to `domain.com/<something>.php` and `/` is excluded from `<something>`. Now what about the exclusion, where you have appended GET parameter(s)?

Comment: Very nice.  As far as exceptions, these pages typically use x as a GET variable, such as page1.php?x=55.  But the false pages listed in Webmaster tools also have variables, but not using the letter x.  I would like any variables that aren't x to be stripped, while allowing only the valid ones to pass.

Comment: As I've written in the **Update** above you can add the `QSA` flag, so all potential `GET` parameters will be passed further when redirecting, then you could catch the ones you need. If that's not a solution for you, is then only one single `GET` parameter that needs to be passed further and if yes, is it always `x` or it might be `y` as well maybe?

Comment: Perfect.  This will certainly work until I can figure out the root cause of the problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert at all on .htaccess, but maybe your redirection rules are confused.
To make a redirect, simply use this in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^some regex$ http://yourdomain.com/page1.php [L]
```

Does your .htaccess looks like that ? Could you update your question with it ?

Answer (score 0):

Look for links to `page1.php/` instead of `page1.php`.

If google (or a browser) follows a link to `page1.php/`, the webserver willl deliver the "correct" file `page1.php`, but google will think that `page1.php` is a directory and therefore interpret relative links (to `page2.php`) like they start from an *index file* in the "directory" `page1.php`.