# htaccess. how to limit dynamic pages to match the database

Tags: php, .htaccess

These are the codes i have added in and we get a The page isn't redirecting properly. Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete. This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

```
<? 
 ob_start(); session_start(); ob_end_clean(); 

$title              = "Antalya Apartments For Sale, Turkey Property";
$slink              = "antalya_apartment.php"; 
$default_bolge      = 4; 
$sql_emlak_turleri  = " ( emlakkayit.eturu='1' ) "; 
$canonical          = "antalya_apartment.php"; 

include "ust.php";

//bolgelerden birisi secilmis ise filtreleme yapilir
if($_GET[bid]>0) { $default_bolge = $_GET[bid]; } 

$sql_ek     = " AND emlakkayit.ilce='".$default_bolge."' "; 

//bolgeler
$sql = "SELECT
        bolge.id,
        bolge.bolge,
        count(emlakkayit.id)
    FROM
        bolge 
        LEFT JOIN emlakkayit ON emlakkayit.ilce=bolge.id 
    WHERE ".$sql_emlak_turleri." 
    GROUP BY bolge.id 
    ORDER BY bolge.bolge ASC " ;    
//$sql = "SELECT id,bolge FROM bolge ORDER BY bolge ASC " ; 
$DB->sorgula($sql); $syc=0;  
while($bolgeler = $DB->satirgetir($DB->sorgu_id))
{
$syc++;
$blg[$syc][id]      = $bolgeler[0];
$blg[$syc][bolge]   = $bolgeler[1];
$blg[$syc][ks]      = $bolgeler[2];
}
$DB->kapat($DB->sorgu_id);

$sql = "SELECT
        bolge.id,
        bolge.bolge,
        count(emlakkayit.id)
    FROM
        bolge 
        LEFT JOIN emlakkayit ON emlakkayit.ilce=bolge.id 
    WHERE 
        ".$sql_emlak_turleri." ".$sql_ek."
    GROUP BY bolge.id 
    ORDER BY bolge.bolge DESC " ;   
$DB->sorgula($sql); $sayac=0;  
while($bolgeler = $DB->satirgetir($DB->sorgu_id))
{
$sayac++;
$bolgeler_dizi[$sayac][id]      = $bolgeler[0];
$bolgeler_dizi[$sayac][bolge]   = $bolgeler[1];
$bolgeler_dizi[$sayac][ks]      = $bolgeler[2];
$toplam_kayit[$bolgeler[0]]     = $bolgeler[2];
if( $default_bolge==$bolgeler[0] ) $iste_bolgemiz = $bolgeler[1] ;
}

if ($sayac == 0) { ob_end_clean(); header('Location: http://www.turkish-property-world.com/antalya_apartment.php'); die; }

$DB->kapat($DB->sorgu_id);
//bolgeler diziye atildi

//paging on hazirlik
$goruntu_sayisi = 5 ;
$toplam_kayit_s = $toplam_kayit[$default_bolge] ;
$off            = "";
$paging_sayfa_sayisi = ceil($toplam_kayit_s / $goruntu_sayisi) ;
if($paging<=0) { $baslangic = 0 ; } else { $baslangic = $paging*$goruntu_sayisi ; }
?>
```

Comment: i would like to give a 404 header for the following urls in htaccess

/antalya_apartment.php?bid=2&page=232
/antalya_apartment.php?bid=2&page=233
/antalya_apartment.php?bid=2&page=234
/antalya_apartment.php?bid=2&page=236
/antalya_apartment.php?bid=2&page=239
/antalya_apartment.php?bid=2&page=241

Comment: Don't do it... this will have a huge negative impact on your SEO. Search engines could start reporting `antalya_apartment.php` as returning a 404, regardless of the URL parameters.

Comment: You're better off simply displaying a message that reads something like `Bid ID #2 doesn't exist.` Or redirecting the user to the last valid results page if the `page` parameter is out of bounds.

Comment: i am afraid i could mess up the php codes. i already know the exact urls causing the problem. 

how can i give a 404 in htaccess for this specific page

/antalya_apartment.php?bid=2&page=232

Comment: is there a way we can adapt something like this perhaps as i have the same issue 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11329834/excluding-strange-pages-with-htaccess?rq=1

Comment: You could redirect those, to your start page or something like that instead of 404, if SEO rating might become a problem. I still would do it in-script, now you know the pages where you have this problem, but there might be more and more showing up in google search later on.

Comment: ok thanks but to make it easy for me, could you please tell me how to write a rule to give a 404 for specific page

 /antalya_apartment.php?bid=2&page=232

then google should after some time drop it from the WMT list

Comment: ok, I will edit my answer to do this as well...

Comment: Also you need to make sure to protect your page against SQL Injection (maybe google for it), in short: you can't trust that the $_GET values are safe! You might at least wrap them into something like `intval()` since those are supposed to be numeric! Eg `$sql_ek = " AND emlakkayit.ilce='".intval($default_bolge)."' ";` ... of course it is even better to use propper escaping like `mysql_real_escape_string()` depending on your underling system...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 404 from script

In your script I would simply check the count of products (before outputting anything), and if there are zero products execute ...

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
die;
```

or in case your page uses FastCGI:

```
header("Status: 404 Not Found");
die;
```

### Recirect to other page

Since the point came up that showing a 404 might mess up SEO results for your page, you might consider redirecting to your start-page (or something similar).

In your `antalya_apartment.php` either with a header redirect, ...

```
header('Location: http://www.turkish-property-world.com/antalya_apartment.php');
die;
```

... or optionally you could also just choose to alter your data (e.g. change your `bid` and `page` vars).

### Logic for specific pages

You could put following right at the top of your php script:

```
if ($_GET['bid']==4 && $_GET['page']==9)
{
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    die;
}
```

In your case to do specific redirects:

```
<? 

// Right at the top do your checking/redirecting/...
if ($_GET['bid']==4 && $_GET['page']==9)
{
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    die;
}

ob_start();  
session_start();

$title              = "Antalya Apartments For Sale, Turkey Property";
$slink              = "antalya_apartment.php"; 
$default_bolge      = 4; 
$sql_emlak_turleri  = " ( emlakkayit.eturu='1' ) "; 
$canonical          = "antalya_apartment.php"; 

include "ust.php";

// ...
```

### Logic to get the product count and redirect whenever there is no result

If you put this right after your while loop, it should redirect every time there are NO products available.

```
// ...
$sql = "SELECT
        bolge.id,
        bolge.bolge,
        count(emlakkayit.id)
    FROM
        bolge 
        LEFT JOIN emlakkayit ON emlakkayit.ilce=bolge.id 
    WHERE 
        ".$sql_emlak_turleri." ".$sql_ek."
    GROUP BY bolge.id 
    ORDER BY bolge.bolge DESC " ;   
$DB->sorgula($sql); $sayac=0;  
while($bolgeler = $DB->satirgetir($DB->sorgu_id))
{
$sayac++;
$bolgeler_dizi[$sayac][id]      = $bolgeler[0];
$bolgeler_dizi[$sayac][bolge]   = $bolgeler[1];
$bolgeler_dizi[$sayac][ks]      = $bolgeler[2];
$toplam_kayit[$bolgeler[0]]     = $bolgeler[2];
if( $default_bolge==$bolgeler[0] ) $iste_bolgemiz = $bolgeler[1] ;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
if ($sayac == 0)
{
    header('Location: http://www.turkish-property-world.com/antalya_apartment.php');
    die;
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////

$DB->kapat($DB->sorgu_id);
//bolgeler diziye atildi

//paging on hazirlik
$goruntu_sayisi = 5 ;
$toplam_kayit_s = $toplam_kayit[$default_bolge] ;
$off            = "";
$paging_sayfa_sayisi = ceil($toplam_kayit_s / $goruntu_sayisi) ;
if($paging<=0) { $baslangic = 0 ; } else { $baslangic = $paging*$goruntu_sayisi ; }
?>
```

Comment: if i send the page php coding, could you please show me which line to add it....pleeeease

Comment: sure, if it is no sensible data it might be better to post it in your question for others to track as well.

Comment: i have included it in the question above thls so much for your wonderful help

Comment: i just modified the page above and ftp the file. still can access pages like this http://bit.ly/1mRvAtH

Comment: oh ok i will now try this one too, Getting the product count and making it individually

Comment: That should be better! Also you copied my first example exactly, but you would need to change those values to suite your case eg `if ($_GET['bid']==4 && $_GET['page']==999) ...`

Comment: not sure where to add part for, Logic to get the product count and redirect whenever there is no result. 

is there a way you could send me the code insert ready to try out.. thankyou

Comment: if i can have one page working, i can modify the other 30 pages accordingly. thks

Comment: ... I modified it to show more of the surrounding code! You have to put it just behind your while loop since there you increment `$sayac` for every record, you know that when it is still `0` that there where no results. (But you should then also really look for escaping your data, to prevent sql injection!)

Comment: Furthermore you might need to call `ob_end_clean()` before `header(..)`, otherwise it might still be buffering whatever you are doing, and therefore only show a blank page!

Comment: hey thanks for all the input. it took me a while to understand this. 

but seems the problem is not a paging loop problem (i mean on page factor) as the page correctly starts here http://bit.ly/1oIK14x and ends here http://bit.ly/1mhJJSk 

when a search is done like here http://bit.ly/QACXe2 the results redirect from the query page to the results page and produced here http://bit.ly/1nFh0qv 

but if you just open the search end page upfront without using the  search query we see this http://bit.ly/1sEvvNy 

so i now understand where Google has indexed the pages.

Comment: so for a temporary fix for now, please advise how i can make a rule in htaccess to give a 404 http response to these SPECIFIC PAGESs so google can deindex them in wmt. 

/antalya_apartment.php?bid=2&page=256 
/antalya_apartment.php?bid=2&page=257 
/antalya_apartment.php?bid=3&page=104 


after deindex i will delete the htaccess rule and see how it goes on in future.

Comment: i tried something like this but no effect RedirectMatch 404 antalya_apartment.php?bid=2&page=230

Comment: For specific redirects take my 3rd approach for example: to redirect `antalya_apartment.php?bid=2&page=256` you could put at the top of the page `if ($_GET['bid'] == 2 && $_GET['page'] == 256)
{
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    die;
}` ... you could extend the if to take other pages as well eg: `if ($_GET['bid'] == 2 && $_GET['page'] == 256  ||  $_GET['bid'] == 2 && $_GET['page'] == 257  ||  $_GET['bid'] == 3 && $_GET['page'] == 104) ...`

Comment: But did you try to insert the dynamic redirect explained in the last point of my answer? Did you find the place where to put the code? The only changes are within the `/////////////////` comments, as you can see pretty close to the end of the script.

Comment: i have tried all, where i add at the very top the 1st two the page doesn't open, when i use 3rd it says The page isn't redirecting properly Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete. when it dd the last one nothing happens

Comment: the best bet to handle seems //////Logic to get the product count and redirect whenever there is no result///// but get no redirect on no product page and still Status: HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Comment: This is probably because you still have output buffering on. You will need to put - in any of these cases - an `ob_end_clean()` before the header, as I have written in a comment before. Eg: `if ($sayac == 0) { ob_end_clean(); header('Location: http://www.turkish-property-world.com/antalya_apartment.php'); die; }`

Comment: when i add this at the top, and add lower the Logic to get the product count and redirect whenever there is no result, i get The page isn't redirecting properly

Comment: This comment was not for the top, it was the logic to put after your while loop, the one within the `///////////////`.  ... I'm just saying, whatever you choose to do, you will need to end your output buffering first! (`ob_end_clean()` for example)

Comment: Yes I saw that, but it is wrong, sry ... I have also edited your question to reflect that, but it has to be peer reviewed first, since I don't have sufficient reputation yet.  1. Delete the part at the top (`$sayac` is not set there!), 2. insert the `ob_end_clean()` in the later section with the ///// right before `header`

Comment: i have edited the question to reflect change... still no redirect when sayac is 0  http://bit.ly/1jbZTgy

Comment: Does the `ust.php` already output some code? In this case a redirect would not work (just one possibility). Maybe I could really help you better by email, since this seems not to be helpful/comprehensible for anyone else having a similar problem. (maybe just set your email in your profile so I can contact you)